# How to make multiple toggle to work in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on jquery script ,where after cliking addmore button ,a particular block of html code is appended.
in each block there is checkbox ,where on click on click on checkbox  some part of html is hidden. my question is to hide each independently.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){

            if($(this).attr("value")=="YES"){
                $(".box").toggle();
                /*$("#ab").html('currently Attending');*/
            }
        });
    });
</script>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#addmore').click(function(){
$('#item2').append("<div class='form-group'><label class='col-sm-4 '>Period</label><div class='col-sm-8'><div class='checkbox'><label><input type='checkbox' value='YES' name='currently_attending'>I`m currently attending this course</label></div><div class='row'><div class='col-xs-3'> Month<select class='span2  form-control' required name='from_month'><option value=''>Month</option><option value='Jan'>Jan</option>\
                                     \ <option value='Feb'>Feb</option>\
                                      <option value='March'>March</option>\
                                      <option value='April'>April</option>\
                                      <option value='May'>May</option>\
                                      <option value='June'>June</option>\
                                      <option value='July'>July</option>\
                                      <option value='Aug'>Aug</option>\
                                      <option value='Sept'>Sept</option>\
                                      <option value='Oct'>Oct</option>\
                                      <option value='Nov'>Nov</option>\
                                      <option value='Dec'>Dec</option>\
                                    </select>\
                                  </div>\
                                 <div class='col-xs-3'>\
                                  Year\
                                      <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='year' name='from_year' required pattern='[0-9]{4,4}'>\
                                  </div>\
                                  <span class='box'>\
                                  <div class='col-xs-3'>\
                                  Month\
                                    <select class='span2 form-control'  name='to_month' >\
                                      <option value=''>Month</option>\
                                      <option value='Jan'>Jan</option>\
                                      <option value='Feb'>Feb</option>\
                                      <option value='March' >March</option>\
                                      <option value='April'>April</option>\
                                      <option value='May'>May</option>\
                                      <option value='June'>June</option>\
                                      <option value='July'>July</option>\
                                      <option value='Aug'>Aug</option>\
                                      <option value='Sept'>Sept</option>\
                                      <option value='Oct'>Oct</option>\
                                      <option value='Nov'>Nov</option>\
                                      <option value='Dec'>Dec</option>\
                                    </select>\
                                  </div>\
                                  <div class='col-xs-3'>\
                                  Year\
                                     <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='year' name='to_year'  >\
                                  </div>\
                                  </span>\
                                  <div id='ab'></div>\
                                </div>\
                              </div>\
                            </div>\
                           <div class='cl'></div>\
                            <div class='form-group'>\
                              <label class='col-sm-4'>Degree / Course title*</label>\
                              <div class='col-sm-8'>\
                                <input type='text' class='form-control ' name='title' required />\
                              </div>\
                            </div>\
                           <div class='cl'></div>\
                                      ")});



});
$("#item2").on("click",".delete", function(){
$(this).closest(".form-group").remove();
});
                             </script>
```

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: @Rahul use this http://jsfiddle.net or try putting your code here in SO code panel

Comment: ok. i am doing it, please wait

Comment: I have posted in http://jsfiddle.net/1hsbzkxw/

Comment: @Rahul, Also you have some messy code for appending the data- This could be done easily with `clone` . Here is the demo- http://jsfiddle.net/1hsbzkxw/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this-**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change','input[type="checkbox"]',function(){
        var boxElement=$(this).closest('.form-group').find('span.box');
        $(this).is(':checked')?boxElement.hide():boxElement.show();

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1hsbzkxw/2/

**Or a toggle way-**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change','input[type="checkbox"]',function(){
        var boxElement=$(this).closest('.form-group').find('span.box');
        boxElement.toggle();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1hsbzkxw/3/

**Explanation-**

```
var boxElement=$(this).closest('.form-group').find('span.box');
```

`$(this)` - is the current target on which event is being triggered, In your case this is a checkbox.

Now from it's hierarchy in the DOM It finds the most immediate(closest) element with calss `.form-group`.
In your case this class is at the most parent `div.form-group`.

**Next-**
Now it searches for the span with class `box`, Apparently inside the class `.form-group`.

Once it finds the element, then it gets the state of this element whether it is hidden or shown on the DOM.

If its hidden then toggle shows it and if its shown toggle hides it. 
That's how toggle works.

Comment: every thing is working fine . i want to understand  the line ,can u explain ,so that it will be helpful in future $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span.box');
        boxElement.toggle();

Comment: @Rahul, Check it now.

Comment: This Explanation will be very useful to me,thanks once again   :)

Comment: @Rahul, Cheers rahul !